# opensuse use rpm install NOKEY problem

Tags: software-installation, opensuse

i facing a problem on installing pcsc-tools on opensuse (server mode), i have download the pcsc-tools from opensuse website flow by this link [https://software.opensuse.org/package/pcsc-tools][1].

unfortunately it need key for the rpm package installation.

Below is the step i try:

1. Install openSUSE-Leap-15.0-NET-x86_64 in vmware virtual player.
2. Hook the usb to the virtual player, and mount usb drive into opensuse.
3. cd to the drive that mount at the folder and use rpm command -i or --force

it show the **Header** **V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 65176565:NOKEY**

Is there any tar package suitable for opensuse, the major version **opensuse-11 sp4 enterprise**  is the one which needed to be installed.

Comment: Have you tried to install it with `zypper`? I don't think the signature output is the error here. Trying to reproduce it I encounter missing dependencies. But installing with zypper works in my case, where I am presented with the additional packages to be installed:

`leap15:~ # zypper in /tmp/pcsc-tools-1.5.3-4.1.x86_64.rpm 
[...]
The following 4 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  libpcsclite1 pcsc-lite pcsc-tools perl-pcsc
[...]
  pcsc-lite`

Comment: @eblock i have try using zypper ar -f https://software.opensuse.org/package/pcsc-tools/rpm/pcsc-tools , i not sure how to install it after command above

Comment: @eblock it works on my vmplayer, how to install zypper in suse11 sp4?

Comment: That's not how it works. `zypper ar` just adds a repository, which in your case is the wrong repo url. If you need sle11sp4 it would look like this: `zypper ar https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/security:/chipcard/SLE_11_SP4/ PCSC-Tools`.

Then you install with `zypper install pcsc-tools`. But you can also simply install the rpm you already downloaded with `zypper in <path-to-rpm>`.

Comment: I don't understand your latest comment "it works on my vmplayer, how to install zypper in suse11 sp4?" Does that mean that your sles11sp4 doesn't have zypper installed? Which would be weird... Or how to install pcsc-tools on a sles11sp4 system? If the latter, then it's the same way as in a leap system using zypper.

Comment: @eblock zypper command works in my vmplayer, opensuse-11 sp4 is installed in server, i use my vmplayer to try all the installation before try it in server, server can connect to any network need to download package ready to install it at once

Comment: I don't know the repos present on your sles11 system, so it's hard to tell if the dependencies are covered.

Comment: @eblock  zypper download link https://pkgs.org/download/zypper  still need to use rpm command to install it, if use rpm command will show NOKEY error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88662/discussion-between-eblock-and-victor).